# Marketing cloud tracking in Journey Builder or Automation Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, email-tracking, tracking-extract

I have a Journey with API event as entry source and then I send emails to these customers.
How can I track the open and clicks in Journey builder. Can export csv data about clicks and opens?

Or should I use automation studio to filter data/sql query(Customer DE) and then use data-extract? Will I then get the data about clicks ?

I am confused, could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Marketing Cloud does not yet have this export to CSV functionality ready. Still the [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003XlzQAE) is left open.

And yes, Automation Studio allows us to [extract the opens and clicks](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5).